# How to convert JSON string to object collection using GSON?

Tags: android, json, gson

I have following class:

```
public class UserObject implements Serializable
{
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public String phoneno;

    public UserObject()
    {
        this.id = new Integer(0);
        this.name = "";
        this.phoneno = "";
   }
}
```

I have a `json` string like following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "First Name",
        "phoneno": "0123452",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Second Name",
        "phoneno": "0123452",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Third Name",
        "phoneno": "0123455",
   }
]
```

I can easily convert from `Collection` of `UserObject` to `JSON` using  following code:

```
Collection users = new Vector();
UserObject userObj = new UserObject();

userObj.id=1; userObj.name="First Name"; userObj.phoneno="0123451";
users.add(userObj);
userObj.id=2; userObj.name="Second Name"; userObj.phoneno="0123452";
users.add(userObj);
userObj.id=3; userObj.name="Second Name"; userObj.phoneno="0123455";
users.add(userObj);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(users);
```

But I am not sure how to convert the `JSON` `string` to the `collection` of `objects`? I have found that I can use `gson.fromJson()` but don't know how to use for `Collection`. Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code allows you to get the `Collection` of `UserObject`

```
Type token = new TypeToken<Collection<UserObject>>() {}.getType();
Collection<UserObject> result = gson.fromJson(json, token);
```

Also, please note that the `json` provided in the question isn't valid, because there is a extra comma after `phoneno` field. Here is the corrent one:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "First Name",
        "phoneno": "0123452"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Second Name",
        "phoneno": "0123452"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Third Name",
        "phoneno": "0123455"
    }
]
```

Comment: Excellent man. Thanks a lot to guide such simple way. It works like magic.

Answer (score 6):

Given this JSON, your wrapper class should look like this:

```
public class Data {
    private List<User> users;
    // +getters/setters
}

public class User {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private List<User> friends;
    // +getters/setters
}
```

and then to convert it, use

```
Data data = gson.fromJson(this.json, Data.class);
```

and to get the users, use

```
List<User> users = data.getUsers();
```

Comment: Can you please add some more details.Still I am not clear. What is wrapper class? Do I need to create a new class Data? what will be the structure and return value of getUsers()?

Comment: @ray yes u need to create a need class data as (DO)  Structure will name and email or you can change accd to your implementation as you need phone number as well