# How to change data in a room database from a JSON file

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-room

I have a main table and I need to completely replace all the data in it with file data from JSON, for example, there are 20 rows in the table, and 15 rows in JSON, how to write or replace rows in the local database room

Not sure how to do it better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To change the data in a Room database using JSON data, you can follow these steps:

1. Parse the JSON data (your JSON file).
2. Clear the existing data(your local DataBase).
3. Insert the new data in local dataBase.

**Example:**

```
// Step 1: Parse the JSON data
val jsonString = // Read the JSON file content
val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonString)

// Step 2: Clear the existing data
yourDao.deleteAllRows() // Assuming your DAO has a method to delete all rows

// Step 3: Insert the new data
for (i in 0 until jsonArray.length()) {
    val jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
    val rowData = // Convert jsonObject to your data model
    yourDao.insert(rowData) // Assuming your DAO has an insert method
}
```

Comment: Hello! Thats my JSON file

```

{"type":"table","name":"lesson","database":"lessondb","data":
[
{"id":"1","lessonName":"ANDROID","groupName":"IST119","day":"1","teachname":"DANILOV","time":"10:20","roomles":"414-2","typeOfWeek":"1"},
{"id":"1","lessonName":"ANDROID","groupName":"IST119","day":"1","teachname":"DANILOV","time":"10:20","roomles":"414-2","typeOfWeek":"1"},
]
}
```

Comment: You need use Gson library to convert JSON string to object, Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15300229/7308789 and you can use this webSite to create object based on json: https://json2csharp.com/code-converters/json-to-pojo